# How to solve this particular difference equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, delay-differential-equations

Considere a real polynomial function $P_n\left(x\right)$ of two variable, when $n$ is a discrete variable and $x$ a continuous variable

where $P_0\left(x\right)=1$

and satisfies the following recurrence relations:

$$P_{n+1}\left(x\right)=\left(x+1\right)\cdot P_n\left(x\right)+x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(P_n\left(x\right)\right).$$

How could I find the explicit solution $P_n\left(x\right)$ for this expression?

And what name do these types of equations receive?

Comment: For all $n$ we have $P_{n+1}(0)=P_n(0)=1$

Comment: And it's equal to it's Taylor series everywhere... + the fact above might be useful?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $P_{n+1} (0) = P_n (0)$?

Comment: @glowstonetrees Yes. In the comment $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the polynomial as: $$P_n(x)=c_{n,0}x^0+c_{n,1}x^1+\cdots+c_{n,n}x^n,$$
apply the recurrence, and you will get a relation among the coefficients.

That is
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n + 1} \right)} {c_{\,n + 1,\,k} x^{\,k} }  = \left( {x + 1} \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k} }  + x{d \over {dx}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k} }  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k + 1} }  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {k\,c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k} }  + \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {c_{\,n,\,k - 1} x^{\,k} }  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {k\,c_{\,n,\,k} x^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$
or
$$
c_{\,n + 1,\,k}  = \left( {1 + k} \right)c_{\,n,\,k}  + c_{\,n,\,k - 1} 
$$
with the understanding that when the index is negative
the coefficient is null.

Since the recursion for Stirling N. of 2nd kind is
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  n \cr 
  m \cr}  \right\} = m\left\{ \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  m \cr}  \right\} + \left\{ \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  m - 1 \cr}  \right\}
$$
then you get
$$
c_{\,n,\,k}  = \left\{ \matrix{
  n + 1 \cr 
  k + 1 \cr}  \right\}
$$
and your polynomials are related to the [Touchard Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials)
$$
P_{\,n} (x) = {1 \over x}T_{\,n + 1} (x)
$$

Comment: Never mind! My Taylor series comment is a red herring. Do it this way.

Comment: @Mason: I saw your comment, but I found it a bit cryptic and expecially not clear on the fact that the coefficients changes with $n$.

Comment: Yes. Like I said: A red herring. This is a far better approach.
Spoilers follow: 
Did you come to:  $c_{n+1,j}=c_{n,j-1}+jc_{n,j}$?

Comment: Also there is no reason that $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ right?

Comment: Ah... maybe there is good reason for that.

Comment: @Mason: a) the recurrence is slightly difference: I transformed my hint into an answer  b) right, in general you do not put an upper bound on the degree (I put that into brackets in fact), but in this case it is obvious that the degree is increasing same as $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The coefficients of the polynomials are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). The [OEIS triangular sequence A008277](http://oeis.org/A008277) has a lot of information about the sequence and the polynomials are almost [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials), except $\;x\;p_n(x) = T_{n+1}(x).\;$  The equation you have where each $\;p_{n+1}(x)\;$ is determined by the previous $\;p_n(x)\;$ is usually called a difference-differential equation.

Note that the recurrence equation can be directly translated into a recurrence relation for the polynomial coefficients which is the usual one for the Stirling numbers of the second kind. This is due to $\;(x+1)\;s(n,k)\;x^k = s(n,k)\;x^k + s(n,k)\;x^{k+1},\;\;$ and $\;x \frac{d}{dx} s(n,k)\;x^k = k\; s(n,k)\;x^k.$

Comment: how did you get to the expression $\;x\;p_n(x) = T_{n+1}(x).\;$

Comment: @Juan Alfaro:   I computed p_n(x) and T_n(x) and noticed they are almost the same except for the factor x for p and the n+1 for T

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment where we show what the first few polynomials look like.

Let's start with $P_0(x)=1$ and see what we can see:

$$P_{1}\left(x\right)=\left(x+1\right)\cdot P_0\left(x\right)+x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(P_0\left(x\right)\right)=(x+1)\cdot 1+x\cdot0=x+1$$

Coefficients being: $[1,1]$

$$P_{2}\left(x\right)=\left(x+1\right)\cdot P_1\left(x\right)+x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(P_1\left(x\right)\right)=(x+1)^2+x=x^2+3x+1$$

Coefficients being: $[1,3,1]$

$P_{3}\left(x\right)$
$=\left(x+1\right) P_2\left(x\right)+x\frac{d}{dx}\left(P_2\left(x\right)\right)=(x+1)^3+x(x+1)+2x^2+3x=x^3+6x^2+7x+1 $

Coefficients being $[1,6,7,1]$

Compare with this table: [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values)

Comment: there is an error in $P_{3}\left(x\right)$  because it's really $P_{3}\left(x\right)=x^3+6x^2+7x+1$ and you dragged error to $P_{4}\left(x\right)$

Comment: Thanks. I am seeing it now.

Comment: Fixed. None of the answers made it clear how you could compute these directly and I just wanted to make that explicit for any onlooker.